# How to identify the type of an object?

Tags: swift, nsarray, nsdictionary, anyobject

Here is my JSON response for a particular API.

**Case 1**

```
  ChallengeConfiguration =     {
            AnswerAttemptsAllowed = 0;
            ApplicantChallengeId = 872934636;
            ApplicantId = 30320480;
            CorrectAnswersNeeded = 0;

            MultiChoiceQuestion =         (
               {
    FullQuestionText = "From the following list, select one of your current or previous employers.";
    QuestionId = 35666244;
    SequenceNumber = 1;
                },
                {
    FullQuestionText = "What color is/was your 2010 Pontiac Grand Prix?";
    QuestionId = 35666246;
    SequenceNumber = 2;
                }
                                           )

    }
```

The key "MultiChoiceQuestion" returns an array with two questions. So here is my code.

```
let QuestionArray:NSArray = dict1.objectForKey("ChallengeConfiguration")?.objectForKey("MultiChoiceQuestion") as! NSArray
```

**Case 2**

```
  ChallengeConfiguration =    

                            {

                AnswerAttemptsAllowed = 0;
                ApplicantChallengeId = 872934636;
                ApplicantId = 30320480;
                CorrectAnswersNeeded = 0;

                MultiChoiceQuestion =         {

        FullQuestionText = "From the following list, select one of your 
 current or previous employers.";

       QuestionId = 35666244;
       SequenceNumber = 1;
                                              }

                                   }
```

For Case 2 my code does not work and app crashes because it returns a dictionary for that specific Key. So how could I write a generic code that would work for all objects?

Comment: Your indentation is very ... creative.

Comment: Nsarray or Array ,that is not an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the key can contain either an array of dictionary values or a dictionary, so you just need to try casting to see which one you have.

so I would likely do it like this:

```
if let arr = dict1.objectForKey("ChallengeConfiguration")?.objectForKey("MultiChoiceQuestion") as? Array {
    // parse multiple items as an array
} else if let arr = dict1.objectForKey("ChallengeConfiguration")?.objectForKey("MultiChoiceQuestion") as? [String:AnyObject] {
   // parse single item from dictionary
}
```

You should never really use ! to force unwrap something unless you are completely certain that the value exists and is of the type you are expecting.

Use conditional logic here to test the response and parse it safely so that your app doesn't crash, even in failure.

Comment: Actually I have declared a NSmutableArray globally .And I am assigning question array on it . GlobalQuestionArray= NSMutablearray(array:questionArray). It is working fine for the array type .Can I use global variable to AnyObject instead of NSmutableArray

Comment: if let arr = dict1.objectForKey("ChallengeConfiguration")?.objectForKey("MultiChoiceQuestion")  {
   globalQuestionArray = arr as? AnyObject (globalQuestionArray taking as an Anyobject )
}

Comment: the only time i use AnyObject is when defining a dictionary to be honest, if you use this anywhere else you still wont know what type it is. you should try to cast to the type you would expect